# Remote login with php curl and simple dom

Tags: php, dom, post, curl, authentication

I'm trying to login to an external form. This form has a dynamic field, so i first load the page to get the field value and set the others fields that I got through the chrome's object inspector

```
$ch = curl_init();
$url = 'https://webvendas.gvt.com.br/siebelview/dealer/login.sv';

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://webvendas.gvt.com.br/siebelview/dealer/login.sv');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,  dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0 );

  $data = curl_exec($ch);


include 'dom/simple_html_dom.php';

$data = str_get_html($data);
$auth = array(
        'AJAXREQUEST' => '_viewRoot',
        'j_id4' => 'user',
        'j_id1' => 'j_id1',
        'password'  => 'password',
        'ajaxSingle'    => 'j_id2',
        'j_id2'     => 'j_id2',
        'javax.faces.ViewState'=>$data->find('input[name="javax.faces.ViewState"]',0)->value,
);
```

After that I post the form, but all I get is a xml with some blank fields. What I am doing wrong?

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,    array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($auth)); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,  dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt');

$data = curl_exec($ch);

echo $data;
```

Comment: So if I understand, you're making 2 cURL requests?  If that's the case, is the first one successful? Is the `str_get_html()` and `$data->find()` bits working like you think they should?

Comment: Yes. I'm making 2 requests. The first one to get the javax.faces.ViewState field value and the second one to post the data and both functions are returning what they should.